# ELKI does not find class gnu/trove/impl/hash/TObjectHash

Tags: java, classloader, elki

I have a dataset consisting of around 10000 samples with two features.  I would like to use ELKI to run the LSDBC algorithm and cluster my dataset.  However, I have not been able to get ELKI to work.  After running elki-0.7.0.jar and inputing my desired settings into the gui, regardless of what settings I pick, I get a long stream of error messages in the console input at the bottom of the gui (I have yet to be able to enter all of my desired settings).  This to me indicates that I am missing some dependency, missed some installation step, or somehow not using the software correctly.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on ELKI, but it is also has one of the only implementations of LSDBC that I have been able to find.  What I'm looking for are step by step, ELI5, instructions to install and run this algorithm on my dataset (which is in an arff file created by WEKA) and output the results as a csv file; namely an output file indicating the cluster assignment of each sample.  I would additionally like to be able to perform a grid search for the optimal k and alpha values (that is, run the algorithm for several values of k and alpha and save each of the results; afterwards I will determine the optimal values).  I am using Mac OS X Yosemite.

I feel as though this should be a relatively straight forward task, but I have not been able to make any progress.  I have copied the error stream that I have been getting below

```
gnu/trove/impl/hash/TObjectHash
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/impl/hash/TObjectHash
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser.<init>(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:127)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser$Parameterizer.makeInstance(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:419)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser$Parameterizer.makeInstance(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:355)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:120)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ClassParameter.instantiateClass(ClassParameter.java:234)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ObjectParameter.instantiateClass(ObjectParameter.java:152)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.AbstractDatabaseConnection$Parameterizer.configParser(AbstractDatabaseConnection.java:184)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.InputStreamDatabaseConnection$Parameterizer.makeOptions(InputStreamDatabaseConnection.java:136)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.FileBasedDatabaseConnection$Parameterizer.makeOptions(FileBasedDatabaseConnection.java:123)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ClassParameter.instantiateClass(ClassParameter.java:234)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ObjectParameter.instantiateClass(ObjectParameter.java:152)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.StaticArrayDatabase$Parameterizer.makeOptions(StaticArrayDatabase.java:210)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ClassParameter.instantiateClass(ClassParameter.java:234)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ObjectParameter.instantiateClass(ObjectParameter.java:152)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.InputStep$Parameterizer.makeOptions(InputStep.java:94)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameterization.TrackParameters.tryInstantiate(TrackParameters.java:213)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask$Parameterizer.makeOptions(KDDTask.java:156)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameterization.TrackParameters.tryInstantiate(TrackParameters.java:213)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication$Parameterizer.makeOptions(KDDCLIApplication.java:79)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameterization.TrackParameters.tryInstantiate(TrackParameters.java:213)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.gui.minigui.MiniGUI.doSetParameters(MiniGUI.java:372)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.gui.minigui.MiniGUI.updateParameterTable(MiniGUI.java:359)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.gui.minigui.MiniGUI$5.tableChanged(MiniGUI.java:277)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(AbstractTableModel.java:275)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.gui.util.ParametersModel.setValueAt(ParametersModel.java:130)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2741)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4723)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.stopCellEditing(AbstractCellEditor.java:85)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:1010)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$MouseInputHandler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:798)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6532)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4522)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.trove.impl.hash.TObjectHash
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser.<init>(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:127)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser$Parameterizer.makeInstance(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:419)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser$Parameterizer.makeInstance(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:355)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:120)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ClassParameter.instantiateClass(ClassParameter.java:234)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ObjectParameter.instantiateClass(ObjectParameter.java:152)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.AbstractDatabaseConnection$Parameterizer.configParser(AbstractDatabaseConnection.java:184)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.InputStreamDatabaseConnection$Parameterizer.makeOptions(InputStreamDatabaseConnection.java:136)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.FileBasedDatabaseConnection$Parameterizer.makeOptions(FileBasedDatabaseConnection.java:123)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ClassParameter.instantiateClass(ClassParameter.java:234)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ObjectParameter.instantiateClass(ObjectParameter.java:152)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.StaticArrayDatabase$Parameterizer.makeOptions(StaticArrayDatabase.java:210)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ClassParameter.instantiateClass(ClassParameter.java:234)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameters.ObjectParameter.instantiateClass(ObjectParameter.java:152)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.InputStep$Parameterizer.makeOptions(InputStep.java:94)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameterization.TrackParameters.tryInstantiate(TrackParameters.java:213)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask$Parameterizer.makeOptions(KDDTask.java:156)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameterization.TrackParameters.tryInstantiate(TrackParameters.java:213)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication$Parameterizer.makeOptions(KDDCLIApplication.java:79)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.AbstractParameterizer.make(AbstractParameterizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.ClassGenericsUtil.tryInstantiate(ClassGenericsUtil.java:252)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.parameterization.TrackParameters.tryInstantiate(TrackParameters.java:213)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.gui.minigui.MiniGUI.doSetParameters(MiniGUI.java:372)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.gui.minigui.MiniGUI.updateParameterTable(MiniGUI.java:359)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.gui.minigui.MiniGUI$5.tableChanged(MiniGUI.java:277)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(AbstractTableModel.java:275)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.gui.util.ParametersModel.setValueAt(ParametersModel.java:130)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2741)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4723)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.stopCellEditing(AbstractCellEditor.java:85)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:1010)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$MouseInputHandler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:798)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6532)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4522)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a lot of documentation, in the JavaDoc and Wiki.

Your error is very basic Java usage and not really related to ELKI.

As you can tell (or google) from the class name not found

```
gnu/trove/impl/hash/TObjectHash
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/impl/hash/TObjectHash
```

you are missing the **GNU Trove** Java library (a dependency of ELKI, but not part of ELKI). Maybe you did not download the **complete (single-jar) version**, but only the minimal download (which assumes you manage the dependencies separately, or have them already, e.g. by using the popular Maven tool).

Answer (score 0):

The new ELKI 0.7.1 release

- includes a README that tells you to use `elki.bat` or `elki.sh` to launch.
- will display an easier to understand warning to tell you your classpath is incomplete.

Nevertheless, the audience of ELKI are *developers* that know how to read a stacktrace.